# Dealing with errors when looping through a list

Tags: python

I am having trouble handling errors when iterating over a list as the title states. I am storing a list of IPs in the ipSrcList and iterating over them to check if they have any data in the geoIp2Database. Issue is it iterates over an ip that's not in the db it breaks the program and I am attempting to learn how to handle that error so it continues to iterate and return the data needed.

```
def getGeoIp(ipSrcList):

    reader = geoip2.database.Reader('./GeoLite2-City.mmdb')
    for ip in ipSrcList:
        try:
            response = reader.city(str(ip))
            end
        
        except ValueError:
            print(f'{ip} not found in the databse')

    
    print(response)
    return response
```

Here is the error I am receiving
228, in _get

```
    raise geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError(
geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError: The address <IP ADDRESS HERE> is not in the database.
```

The issue is that the program should continue to iterate through the list until all are iterated.

Comment: What part isn't working? Other than the random `end` it's a normal list iteration?

Comment: This isn't clear. Is the problem that the error is something other that a `ValueError`? If so, let the traceback be your guide as to what error you need to catch.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted code is simply a function that you don't call.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Please explain exactly what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Comment: so the part that isn't working is that when an IP address that is stored in the list "ipSrcList" is not in the database here "reader = geoip2.database.Reader('./GeoLite2-City.mmdb'" it will stop the program and thus stop the iterating through the list.

Comment: So you're just catching a wrong error. Just as the traceback says, you need to be catching `geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError` and not `ValueError`.

Comment: great idea but, when I add that I get...
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ipaddress.py", line 53, in ip_address
    raise ValueError('%r does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address' %
ValueError: '0' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
(cyb339) aroe@aroes-MacBook-Pro week4 %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
try: 
    # Do some work
except ValueError:
    # Handle the exception of type ValueError or any of its sub-classes.
```

The problem is that the code is raising an error of type geoip2.errors.AddressNotFoundError, which is a subclass of RuntimeError, not ValueError.  (ValueError and RuntimeError are both [subclasses of Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).)

If that doesn't make it clear to you, then read up on Python exception handling in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) or your favorite Python book.  Here are the key points from the Python docs:

> Then if [the error's] type matches the exception named after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then execution continues after the try statement.

> A class in an except clause is compatible with an exception if it is the same class or a base class thereof (but not the other way around — an except clause listing a derived class is not compatible with a base class).